# How to filter the item names only when extracting the text from the receipt using Google ML kit?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-mlkit

How can I filter the item names from the list of text that i got from receipt scanner  using goolge ML kit in flutter ?

Actually what i need is list of item names but the Google ML kit is extracting all the text in the reciept.

I tried to extract the item names of the reciept from a grocery store using the Google ML kit package in flutter. It's able to recognize and extract the text from the receipt, but the problem is it is giving all the text from the reciept but I only need the item names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inapp_flutter_kyc](https://pub.dev/packages/inapp_flutter_kyc) package. Here in backend it uses Google ML kit. For ID Card Scanning, you can consider two cases, where the keyword and value are inline and the keyword and the value are in the next line.
In `EkycServices().openImageScanner()` function, pass the keyword name and a boolean -> if the keyword and the value are inline pass true -> if the keyword and the value are not inline pass false.
For example

```
Map<String, bool> keyWordData = {
    'Name' : false,
    'Date of Birth' : true,
    'NID No' : false
  };
```

Now pass this keyWordData to EkycServices().openImageScanner()

```
ExtractedDataFromId? extractedDataFromId;
extractedDataFromId = await EkycServices().openImageScanner(keyWordData);
```

Thus you can get the item names and its corresponding value. Let me know if it helps.